# wxMaxima: how to get a new line using printf?

Tags: printf, maxima

[The documentation](https://maths.cnam.fr/Membres/wilk/MathMax/help/Maxima/maxima_75.html#Item_003a-printf) for `printf` lists

```
   ~%       new line
   ~&       fresh line
```

however, I get the following in wxMaxima:

```
printf(false, "line one ~% line two");
   > line one  line two

printf(false, "line one ~& line two");
   > line one  line two
```

I've tried a few different experiments,  but can't seem to find anything that actually returns something on a new line. Any ideas? Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: The doc link doesn't work

Comment: Strange, I just tried it & It worked for me, so not sure what the issue is (nb: you'll have to search `printf` on the page, as they don't have HTML anchors within the doc, for different entries): http://maths.cnam.fr/Membres/wilk/MathMax/help/Maxima/maxima_75.html

Comment: http->https redirect rule on CNAM's web server is broken. I directly changed the link to https in your question, so that no redirect is necessary. Added the printf anchor too.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference in this case, but the linked-to documentation is out of date; you can find up to date documentation at: https://maxima.sourceforge.io/documentation.html

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior you showed. In both wxMaxima and command line Maxima, I am seeing the output on 2 line, as expected. I am working w/ wxMaxima 19.07 and Maxima post-5.44 (development version). Can you try the same input in command line Maxima and report what you get? Also, what is the output of `build_info();`?

Comment: @RobertDodier -- I don't know how to use the command line version. We're ~12 days from our beta launch, so I haven't had the time to look into it, yet (the initial installation of wxM took me a while to sort out, so I was hesitant to dive into more unknown). Here is the output: `(version="5.36.1",timestamp="2015-05-06 11:10:10",host="x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0",lisp_name="SBCL",lisp_version="1.2.10")`

Comment: @xhienne may I ask how you got the anchor? Thank you for adding it & updating the redirect. I always access via google search and go with the first ref related to what I'm looking for. I'll have to set a bookmark to the correct one.

Comment: @RobertDodier I installed the newest possible version for my machine (`build_info(version="5.43.0",timestamp="2019-06-05 13:14:43",host="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0",lisp_name="SBCL",lisp_version="1.5.3",maxima_userdir="/Users/RaxAdam/.maxima",maxima_tempdir="/var/folders/12/r6_z0thj2t72t20nd655v_zr0000gn/T",maxima_objdir="/Users/RaxAdam/.maxima/binary/5_43_0/sbcl/1_5_3",maxima_frontend="wxMaxima",maxima_frontend_version="19.05.7")` but am still getting the same output for `printf`. I'm looking into running maxima from terminal, now & will update.

Comment: @RobertDodier & the terminal version does indeed print on two lines. Unfortunately, I'm still having the issue with wxM & the STACK-based version we're implementing. I'll post here if I figure out the root cause.

Comment: @RaxAdaam I got the anchor by looking into the page's html code. But this is not how I should have done it in the first place. Just go to the index, click on "P" then "printf" and voilà!

Comment: Are you sure you installed the latest version correctly? Your issue looks very much like [this known bug](https://github.com/wxMaxima-developers/wxmaxima/issues/76) which was only fixed in 2016. Besides, your latest version on MacOS might not be new enough: I also noticed there was a [double-newline bug](https://github.com/wxMaxima-developers/wxmaxima/issues/203) until mid-2020 (just an idea: what if you removed those space characters around  `~%`?)

Comment: OK, I've installed wxMaxima 20.06 on macOS via MacPorts, and I can reproduce the behavior reported here (`printf(false, "foo~%bar~%")` outputs everything on one line). From the bug report linked by @xhienne (https://github.com/wxMaxima-developers/wxmaxima/issues/203) it appears that's the same bug. Version 20.06 is presumably from June 2016, so we need to find 20.08 or later (or, I guess, 20.07 built after bug 203 was fixed) to install.

Comment: For the record, I installed wxMaxima 20.07 (from https://github.com/wxMaxima-developers/wxmaxima/releases) and it has the same bug as what's reported here. I wasn't able to find a more recent binary release, but if I do I will post a note here.